# Comparing Matching Values across two Large Datasets

Tags: mysql

I have two sets of CSV files (with approximately 1.1 Billion total lines in each).

the first CSV set has the following columns:
MessageID,SentTime,state,error

The second CSV set has the following columns:
MessageID, UpdateTime, RecievedTime

Both sets contain duplicate records.  MessageID is an alphanumeric string (approx. 30-50 characters) and is not sorted in any way.

I would like to be able to find a list of all MessageID values that appear in both CSV sets (as well as those that do not) in the most effiecient manner given the large sizes. I was looking at loading it into a mysql database, but the performance from loading it in with the primary key already defined looked like it would take weeks to complete.  Loading everything in and then creating the key might be feasible, but I'm not sure if the presence of duplicate message-ids would make the inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, consider using `cut`, `sort`, `diff`, etc to do the task.

To do it in MySQL, `LOAD FILE` into a table without a `PRIMARY KEY`, then `ALTER` to add the PK; that will be faster than having the Pk already defined.

Since there might be dups on MessageID...  If you want to eliminate dups; elaborate.  If you want to keep dups, then

```
ALTER TABLE t
    ADD id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(MessageID, id),   -- to make matching on MessageID faster
    ADD INDEX(id);   -- to keep auto_inc happy
```

Be sure to have `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set appropriately; that will be the main thing for performance.

Use `JOIN` for seeing what is common; `LEFT JOIN` for seeing what is in one list but not the other.